# Symfony 2, passing variable

Tags: php, javascript, symfony, tinymce

So how can I pass a variable into a script that is not connected with symfony?
For example, I have variable `$a`, which I render in template `a.html.php`
How can I use this `$a` in some `example.php` script?

More close: I wanna make image uploading with TinyMCE image manager; but each user should have their own directory (which corresponds to user id). So I should pass variable user_id to `config.php` file of image manager.

So this directory depends on the user's session! How can I make different dirs to upload images for each user? Or can you advise me how to deal with this problem?

Maybe to use another text editor? Which one can I connect with symfony or to use different directories for different users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store information in the session if you want to share it with other scripts. Make a `var_dump($_SESSION)` in example.php to see what you already have.

Comment: mm, it shows `null` result; mb cause session cant spread on file, required by js

Comment: did you use `session_start()` before?

Comment: oh my god, it works! dunno mb problem was in cache or smth else * and i even tryed before i wrote here O: unbelievable! thx alot! mb i have "curved hands") so thx thx! dunno why it didnt worked before! thx alot

Answer (score 0):

```
$formPath = 'nameBundle:name:name.html.twig';
            $session = $controler->getRequest()->getSession();
            $session->set('formPath', $formPath);
            $session->set('neededVariables', $neededVariables);
return $controler->redirect($controler->generateUrl('show_result'));
```

I used this to handle data and read data function

```
public function showResultAction() {
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $formPath = $session->get('formPath');
    $neededVariables = $session->get('neededVariables');
    if ($formPath or $neededVariables)
        return $this->render($formPath,$neededVariables); else
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('The product does not exist');
}
```